# I am building a API with FastAPI but I don't know how to use a database that already has records. I do not need to create the records just do queries

Tags: database, fastapi

This is the connection I created with SQLite:

```
def show(min_depth: float | None = None, max_depth: float | None = None, min_mag: float | None = None, max_mag: float | None = None, lat_min: float | None = None, lat_max: float | None = None, long_min: float | None = None, long_max: float | None = None, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    sismos = db.query(models.Sismos).filter(models.Sismos.deepth > min_depth).filter(models.Sismos.deepth < max_depth).filter(models.Sismos.mag > min_mag).filter(models.Sismos.mag < max_mag).filter(models.Sismos.lat > lat_min).filter(models.Sismos.lat < lat_max).filter(models.Sismos.lng > long_min).filter(models.Sismos.lng < long_max).all()
    return sismos
```

But all the tutorials show how to post records to fill the table. What I need is to create a connection with a table that already has above 10000 records and filtering it. I need to retrieve the information from a table that contains thousands of records using the function show, filtering the data according to the user necessities.

I need to create queries that help the user.

Comment: What you're showing is the query you are trying to execute. Do you have the connection string and options as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#import-the-sqlalchemy-parts)

Comment: That's the connection I created, but I need to do it to a PSQL server with data.

```from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./sismos.db"
# SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()```